# Rails bug? updating instance variable with array not always working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, rails-activerecord, pry

If I create an instance variable of a user within the Users controller, then try to add to a field array, I can see it has been added, but when I go to save, it does not save

```
@instructor = User.find(current_user.id)
@instructor.clients = @instructor.clients << User.last.id
@instructor.save
```

When I then go to Pry and do the same exact operation with an instance variable I create in Pry, it does save. Why is that and how can I get this to work in the controller?

The array field is a postgres numeric array.

Comment: Define “does not save”. Do you get an error? Does `save` return `false`? Does the record just not appear in the database? Are you positive you’re running *exactly* those three lines only?

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but you can just use `@instructor.clients << User.last_id`. The assignment (`@instructor.clients = @instructor.clients << User.last_id`) is superfluous.

Comment: No error, it returns true. In fact, when I am in pry and I try to save the instance variable from the controller it saves as try, but does not actually save the record. Same exact operation on an instance variable I make in pry, it saves true and saves the record

Comment: did you try brackets, like (@instructor.clients << User.last.id) ?

Comment: yes, I tried brackets in the controller, no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that this:

```
@instructor.clients = @instructor.clients << User.last.id
```

doesn't actually change `@instructor.clients` in a way that ActiveRecord will know about.

For example:

```
>> a = [ ]
>> b = a << 6
>> b.object_id
=> 2165471260
>> a.object_id
=> 2165471260
```

Same `object_id` means the same array and no one (but you) will know that `a` has actually changed.

So `@instructor.clients` is the same object before you add `User.last.id` to it as it is after you've pushed `User.last.id` onto it and ActiveRecord won't realize that you've changed anything. Then you `@instructor.save` and it successfully does nothing at all.

You need to create a new array:

```
@instructor.clients = @instructor.clients + [ User.last.id ]
```

The [`Array#+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-2B) creates a whole new array and that will let ActiveRecord know that something has changed. Then your `@instructor.save` will actually write the new array to the database and the updated array will be there the next time you pull that instructor out of the database.